# HIgher Order Interaction Variables. How to use them in model?

Tags: statistics, feature-selection, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, kaggle

http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/webbooks/logistic/chapter2/

This above website gives an example about using interaction effect between variables. Interacting variables are multiplied and used in the model.However I have read on Kaggle on using 3 or 4-way interaction effect. I use Xgbfi to find interactions but how do I use it in model ?

I have read on kaggle about hashing , bayesian coding and other few techniques. Kindly elaborate on using such 3 or 4-way interaction among **Categorical** , **Numerical variables** and between **Cat - Num Vars** in my model. Example codes using Python or R is also highly welcomed. Thank You.